# Find an amount of subintervals containing an interval from a given set

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

A closed interval [a, b] and a set S of it's closed subintervals [l_i, r_i], i = 1..n, are given.

Consider a set C of [a, b]'s closed subintervals such that each [c_j, d_j] from C non-strictly contains (at least one) interval from S, e. g. for each j = 1..m exists i such c_j <= l_i <= r_i <= d_j.

Find m = |C|, e. g. an amount of items in C.

All numbers here are nonnegative integers.

An obvious solution would be to iterate through every single possible subinterval, witch itself takes O(l^2) time, where l = b - a,  and then for each subinterval we iterate through S and check if it contains any of [l_i, r_i]'s, witch would take O(n).

So resulting complexity would be O(l^2*n), so if l and n are proportional, this results in a qubic complexity. I wounder if faster solution can be derived.

Comment: Just to confirm, you want the count of closed intervals that contain at least 1 element of S. Am I right to assume that the endpoints are always integers?

Comment: Yes, @Dave, you are absolutely correct.

Comment: Also elements of S are also subintervals themselves, but I guess that doesn't make much difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sketch of how to do this:

Parse S, building a map: left_to_right, which has as keys the left endpoints of S, and as values the associated right endpoints. If the same left endpoint is repeated, store the smallest associated right endpoint.

E.g.,

```
say our range is [1, 20], and S = {[3,7], [5,10], [15,17]}
left_to_right = {3 => 7, 5 => 10, 15 => 17}
count = 0 # count of ranges that we'll eventually return
```

We then parse the keys of left_to_right in descending order.

```
parse 15: 
    count += 15 * (20 - 17 + 1) # because each of 1-15 on the left can be paired with each of 17-20 on the right to include this interval
    store smallest_right_used = 17
parse 5:
    count += 5 * (16 - 10 + 1) # because each of 1-5 on the left can be paired with each of 10-16 on the right; 17+ on the right have already been counted.
    store smallest_right_used = 10
parse 3:
    count += 3 * (9 - 7 + 1) # because each of 1-3 on the left can be paired with each of 7-9 on the right, and 10+ on the right have already been counted.
```

In the example, we count the number of intervals containing [15, 17], then the number of intervals containing [5, 10] but not [15, 17], then the number of intervals containing [3, 7] but not [5, 10] (or [15, 17]).

Comment: Seems fine to me.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy This is why we track the smallest right used. Sorry if this was unclear, but we can only take right endpoints smaller than the smallest right endpoint already used. It works fine in your example.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Let me know if it's still unclear to you and I'll write code you can execute.

Comment: It works. Thank you! removing my comments...